# Legal to verify identity using only a specific form of ID?

Tags: united-states

A liquor store verifies shoppers’ age through state-issued driver licenses. It won’t accept, for example, passports.  Legal?

Comment: This probably depends on the specific state, but most likely they're in their rights to not accept passports as proof of age.  Violating regulations and laws for serving alcohol results in stiff penalties, so while selling alcohol is highly profitable they have incentives to make sure they only sell to people they are certain are of the right age; most people aren't familiar with what a Ukrainian passport looks like, fake or otherwise, for example, so there's no way for them to know if it's real or not without a lot of training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, in the US it is not anywhere illegal to refuse to sell alcohol to a person, except when it falls into a enumerated category of prohibited discrimination (e.g. based on sex, religion, race etc). The ID requirement is a "defense" usable by the seller against consequences for accidentally selling to a minor: if they presented acceptable ID, you will not be prosecuted / fined for an underage sale. In Washington, a passport is one of the accepted forms of ID under [WAC 314-11-025](http://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=314-11-025); it also accepted in [California](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=BPC&sectionNum=25660.), idem [Ohio](http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/4301.639), [Florida](https://www.flrules.org/gateway/RuleNo.asp?ID=61A-3.052) and [Wyoming](https://law.justia.com/codes/wyoming/2010/Title12/chapter6.html). Without a law compelling an alcohol vendor to sell their goods to any of-age person with money, it is legal to decline to sell on any grounds other that demographic discrimination.